# Configure/increase MongoDB shell history length

Tags: mongodb, shell, windows-8.1

I want to see MongoDB shell history. I searched on google then I found that all the shell history are stored in `.dbshell` file.

1) Is there any command or tricky way to see MongoDB Shell history in MongoDB Shell??

2) What is default MongoDB shell history length???

3) How to configure/increase MongoDB shell history length??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> 1) Is there any command or tricky way to see MongoDB Shell history in MongoDB Shell??

I'm not aware of a `mongo` shell helper to view the full history, however you can use `cat()`, for example:

```
cat("/Users/myhomedir/.dbshell")
```

There are also keyboard shortcuts:

- <kbd>Up arrow</kbd> - previous history item
- <kbd>Down arrow</kbd> - next history item
- <kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd> - reverse search history
- <kbd>Ctrl+S</kbd> - forward search history

> 2) What is default MongoDB shell history length???

100 items (ref: [`linenoise.cpp`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/v2.6/src/mongo/shell/linenoise.cpp#L142))

> 3) How to configure/increase MongoDB shell history length??

As at MongoDB 2.6, this is hardcoded. You could potentially change the source & recompile, but that's a lot of effort for a small feature.

You should upvote/watch [SERVER-8417: Allow setting of shell history length](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-8417) in the MongoDB issue tracker.